# Refresh Chrome Tab

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, chromium, gedit

Is there a way to refresh an opened tab of chrome (or chromium) from terminal?
(using ubuntu 10.04).

I need this to gedit shortcut to refresh chrome each time I save the file I am editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the livereload extension.  It has a separate inotify ruby script that will automatically refresh your tab whenever a specific file changes.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not have the best integration with Ubuntu, I wouldn't count on finding a way for you to control it through the command line.